# Settings not saving when deployed

Tags: c#, winforms, application-settings

This is a weird issue, when I run the application from Visual Studio and change the settings, the settings change and are stored in the configuration file.

If I copy the files to a public location and do the same the settings are also changed, stored and on next load show the new values.

However when the software is deployed onto a users machine (with InnoSetup) the settings are not saved, so when the software is reloaded it loads the default values.

Is there something I am missing here?  The file is located in the install directory (Program Files x86) and is not read only.

Scope is User and even running the software as administrator doesn't save the changes

```
private void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Properties.Settings.Default.ShowActiveSupportForm = (cboxActiveSupportSplash.Items[cboxActiveSupportSplash.SelectedIndex].ToString() == "Yes");
    Properties.Settings.Default.ActiveSupportSplashColour = SplashColor.R + "," + SplashColor.G + "," + SplashColor.B;
    Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
    if (Application.OpenForms["frmActiveSplash"] != null)
    {
        frmActiveSplash frm = (frmActiveSplash) Application.OpenForms["frmActiveSplash"];
        ColorConverter colorConverter = new ColorConverter();
        Color color = (Color)colorConverter.ConvertFromString(SplashColor.ToArgb().ToString());
        color = Color.FromArgb(255, color.R, color.G, color.B);
        frm.BackColor = color;
    }
    MessageBox.Show("Changes have been saved", "Changes Saved", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
    Properties.Settings.Default.Reload();
    Close();
}
```

Comment: silly question but when you release the code are you pushing the release from the `Debug || Release` folder..?

Comment: What is the scope for the setting? (See the "Settings" tab of your project properties.) If it's "Application" and the user is not an administrator, it's likely that the setting will not be saved.

Comment: @MethodMan from the release folder

Comment: @MatthewWatson Scope is user, running the software as administrator (users have local admin rights) doesn't solve the issue either

Comment: Which OS are you running this on? Are these settings mirrored in the user data folder i.e. not your local .config file in the runtime directory??

Comment: @RorySolley Windows 8.1 and 7, loocing in the user AppData\Local folder it isn't changing the value there either

Comment: @RorySolley Correction it is changing the file, however when you reload the file it reverts back to the initial values.

Comment: Neo, I'm tracking this same issue right now as well. I noticed that this happens only on my multi-line textbox input fields, they happen to be my SQL settings, and not my regular App strings that I have in a separate settings file. Still investigating.

Comment: Neo, I just solved my problem. I had a separate SQL settings, and App settings file, and only values in the App settings file worked. Removing the SQL settings file for now fixed my issue, but I cant quite figure out why.

Comment: This turned out to be some rogue code running in another file that was refreshing the settings, for your issue I'd expect that to happen, but not sure why you have two setting files?